# How to draw metaballs

Tags: java, graphics

I have a bunch of circles with specific radii that I want to render as metaballs. Here's what I mean:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As they get closer together, they start to merge. How can I render this in an efficient manner (e.g. hundreds of circles at 60 fps)? Is it possible?

**EDIT**

Well here's the basic structure of my Ball class...

```
public void Ball
{
    private float x, y, xspeed, yspeed, radius;

    public Ball( ... ) { ... }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g, ArrayList<Ball> balls)
    {
        // render as metaball?
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on "metaballs" and "metasurfaces"

Comment: Even if I didn't know the term 'metaball', is this still not a valid question? Why the close votes?

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins I think it is a valid question, the close votes are probably because you did not include any code...

Comment: `{ .. TO DO ..}` doesn't really count as *code*. Is your question "how to render" or "I can render, but it seems to be slow"? In the first case it's not an SO question, in the second cause you need to show your code.

Comment: Am I the only one who reads this as "meatballs" and gets to the end of the question wondering where all the meatballs are?